# Django richtextupload field error with search

Tags: django, django-models, model, ckeditor

I try to search a field on a model,
The field is RichTextUploadingField, so the search is not working in django admin.

ANY IDEAS??

I take this error
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'search' for RichTextUploadingField or join on the field not permitted.

To solve the bug and find the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.